# API Platform documentation for custom normalizer

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

I am using API Platform and I followed [this tutorial](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/serialization/) to add a custom serialized field which relies on an external service. The `avatar` property needs to be exposed using the `Packages` class.

```
<?php

namespace App\Serializer;

use App\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\Asset\Packages;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\UrlHelper;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ContextAwareNormalizerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ObjectNormalizer;

class UserNormalizer implements ContextAwareNormalizerInterface
{
    /**
     * @var Packages
     */
    private $packages;

    /**
     * @var UrlHelper
     */
    private $urlHelper;

    /**
     * @var ObjectNormalizer
     */
    private $normalizer;

    public function __construct(Packages $packages, UrlHelper $urlHelper, ObjectNormalizer $normalizer)
    {
        $this->packages = $packages;
        $this->normalizer = $normalizer;
        $this->urlHelper = $urlHelper;
    }

    public function normalize($user, $format = null, array $context = [])
    {
        /** @var array */
        $data = $this->normalizer->normalize($user, $format, $context);
        $avatar = null;

        if ($user->getAvatarFilename()) {
            $path = $this->packages->getUrl('uploads/avatars/'.$user->getAvatarFilename());
            $avatar = $this->urlHelper->getAbsoluteUrl($path);
        }

        $data['avatar'] = $avatar;

        return $data;
    }

    public function supportsNormalization($data, $format = null, array $context = [])
    {
        return $data instanceof User;
    }
}
```

The problem is that this property doesn't appear in the documentation as it's added by the custom normalizer. How can I add documentation for it (eg. type, example etc...)?

Answer (score 1):

if this still relevant for you or somebody else:
You can add a custom field to the openapi model with this: https://api-platform.com/docs/core/swagger/#overriding-the-openapi-specification

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I abandoned API Platform and went back to FOSRestBundle.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `$avatar` field to your entity.

Comment: The problem is that I already have an `avatarFilename`, should I add a "dummy" `avatar` property not mapped with Doctrine? It seems kinda hacky, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Like you suggest in the comments you could add a not mapped property to your entity and document it in the annotations, and yes it's hacky like they said [here](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/api-platform-security/custom-field#play)!... it is suggested in the SymfonyCast tutorials

> Just remember the downside to this approach: our documentation has no
> idea that this isMe field exists. If we refresh this page and open the
> docs for fetching a single User... yep! There's no mention of isMe. Of
> course, you could add a public function isMe() in User, put it in the
> user:read group, always return false, then override the isMe key in
> your normalizer with the real value. That would give you the custom
> field and the docs. But sheesh... that's... getting kinda hacky.